# PDE with measure-valued right hand sides?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am looking for a basic set of notes/text that deals with the basics of PDEs with measure valued right hand sides. Even an answer here that answers the following questions would be good:

1) A precise formulation of the problem. I assume it's something like wanting to solve
$$-\Delta u = \delta$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.

2) Function spaces used in this field, and what elementary theorems/techniques are used to obtain well-posedness? (For example, in the ordinary elliptic case I would say: Sobolev spaces with Lax-Milgram etc etc).

Thank you

Comment: I may be mistaken, the first question looks like the question of finding a Green's function to a PDE. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function for example.

Comment: @user35959 OP was not asking for the solution of $-\Delta u = \delta$, he is just illustrating his "measure-valued" data using Dirac delta, for Dirac delta can be viewed as a measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might like this [monograph](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0668). Also, take a look in his [site](http://perso.uclouvain.be/augusto.ponce/). Ponce studied with Brezis, so it is worth to take a look in his work and also on Brezis work. Brezis has some papers about solving partial differential equations involving measures: take a look [here](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~brezis/publications.html).

Comment: That's very good thanks. Do you know any concise document that describes measure theory required for this kind of PDE study? The usual books on measure theory I find very hard to read since they're full of boring-looking lemmas and theorems..

Comment: I know do you feel @michael_faber, I also dont have patience with those books of measure, however, there is one book of Evans that I like it. It is not a treatise on the subject, but it is concise, clear and fast, and in the end you can have a general view of the matter. Take a look on it, it is chapter 1: http://www.amazon.com/Measure-Properties-Functions-Advanced-Mathematics/dp/0849371570/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1372623176&sr=8-1&keywords=evans+measure#reader_0849371570